What is wrong with my Prenex normal form?
I had this equation $$∃yG(y)→¬(∀xF(x,y)↔G(y)).$$
Then I turned it to $$∀y(¬G(y))  \lor ∀x(F(x,y))\land ¬G(y)  \lor ∃x(¬F(x,y))\land G(y).$$
Then I turned it to Prenex normal form: $$∀k∀s∃m(¬G(k)  \lor F(s,y)\land  ¬G(y)  \lor ¬F(m,y)\land G(y)).$$
My professor says that something is wrong with my last equation. She said that I used too many quantifiers and changed the meaning of the original equation.  But how? I'm just following the usual procedures to obtain the Prenex normal form. How can I fix my equation?

Did the exercise require you to put the whole expression in prenex form? What exactly was the question you were supposed to answer?

(I am just as puzzled as you about what could be wrong. I do not see a mistake.)

Yes. The exercise requires to put the whole expression in prenex form. This is the goal of the exercise

She said that sometimes you can rename variable, but sometmes you can't. And she said this is the mistake.  She told me to compare connected varible in the original equation and in the equation that i got. Have no idea what to do

I think you and I read the original formula as $$(\exists yG(y))→¬((\forall xF(x,y))↔G(y)).$$ I wonder if it’s possible to confirm whether your professor reads it the same way.


$$\color{violet}{∃yG(y)}→¬(∀xF(x,\color{blue} y)↔G(\color{blue}y))$$
$$\color{violet}{∀y(¬G(y))}  \lor ∀x(F(x,\color{blue}y))\land ¬G(\color{blue}y)  \lor ∃x(¬F(x,\color{blue}y))\land G(\color{blue}y)$$

$$∀k(¬G(k))  \lor \color\red{\bigg(}∀x(F(x,y))\land ¬G(y)\color\red{\bigg)} \lor \color\red{\bigg(}∃x(¬F(x,y))\land G(y)\color\red{\bigg)}$$
$$∀k(¬G(k))  \lor \color\red{\bigg(}∀\color{green}s(F(\color{green}s,y))\land ¬G(y)\color\red{\bigg)} \lor \color\red{\bigg(}∃\color{green}m(¬F(\color{green}m,y))\land G(y)\color\red{\bigg)}$$

$$∀k∀s∃m(¬G(k)  \lor F(s,y)\land  ¬G(y)  \lor ¬F(m,y)\land G(y))$$


Your three formulae are indeed equivalent to one another. Perhaps your instructor doesn't like you letting same variable $(y)$ have both bound (violet) and free (blue) occurrences (so, we change all bound occurences of $y$ to a new variable, $k),$ or wants you to show more steps.
Note that your omission of those two pairs of parentheses (in red) relies on the convention of treating 'AND' as having having a higher precedence than 'OR'. Since this convention is common but not universal, I would write out those parentheses.

Addendum

The formula that I provided is identical to the original given to me.

In (informal) mathematical writing, a formula like your
$$∃yG(y)→¬(∀xF(x,y)↔G(y))$$ sometimes has implied parentheses $$∃y\color\red{\Big(}G(y)→¬(∀xF(x,y)↔G(y))\color\red{\Big)}$$ inferred from the context. However, your exercise is presumably from some discrete maths class, in which case such ambiguity or reading against the text really shouldn't be necessary, in which case the standard convention is that quantifiers bind more strongly than logical connectives, as above.

I think you were reading the formula (incorrectly) as:
$$
\Big(\exists yG(y)\Big)\to \neg\Big(\forall xF(x,y)\leftrightarrow G(y)\Big)
$$
But the formula is really:
$$
\exists y\Big(G(y)\to \neg(\forall xF(x,y)\leftrightarrow G(y))\Big)
$$
Because of this, I think you to renamed some of the $y$'s but not all of them, and also added extra quantifiers. This changes the meaning significantly. I would simplify this to:
$$
\exists y\Big(\neg G(y)\vee \big(\forall xF(x,y)\wedge \neg G(y)\big)\vee \big(\exists x\neg F(x,y)\wedge G(y)\big)\Big)\\
\vdots
$$
You can proceed from here. I advise using more parentheses to keep track of the logical structure.

I was wondering if this was the problem, but every source I look at implies that the first interpretation is the correct one. Do you have a reference for your interpretation?

What this interpretation has going for it is that you don;t have any free variables, unlike the formula posted by the OP.  Not that that clinches it ... the OP will have to check parentheses on original question.

Thank you for the answers, I will ask the professor about the parentheses. The formula I provided is identical to the original. Maybe it’s really a mistake, or perhaps I missed some small detail during the lecture about how to do this exercise

@Пчеловод "The formula I provided is identical to the original." Then I'd say that your reading is the correct one, and if your instructor actually did mean Logan's suggested reading, then they simply should not have omitted that essential outermost pair of parentheses.
